# Parsing JSON-like String with Nested Quotes in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to parse a JSON-like string in Python, but I'm running into issues with nested quotes. Specifically, the string contains quotes within quotes, which is causing the JSON parser to fail. Here's an example of the problematic string:

```
{
  "text": "This is a "test" string",
  "another_key": "Another value"
}
```

As you can see, the value for the key "text" contains additional quotes around the word "test", which is causing the problem.

I've tried various approaches to clean the string and convert it to a Python dictionary, but none have worked so far. Here's an example function I tried:

```
def clean_and_convert_to_dict(input_str):
    new_str = ''
    in_string = False
    for char in input_str:
        if char == '"':
            in_string = not in_string

        if in_string:
            if char == '"':
                new_str += '\\"'
            elif char == '\n':
                new_str += '\\n'
            else:
                new_str += char
        else:
            if char != '\n':
                new_str += char
    try:
        return json.loads(new_str), "Conversion successful."
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        return None, f"Conversion error: {e}"
```

This function attempts to escape the nested quotes, but it's not working as expected. I'm looking for a function that can correctly handle these nested quotes and convert the string to a Python dictionary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried to write a Python function that would clean the string by escaping the nested quotes so that it could be successfully converted to a Python dictionary using json.loads(). I expected the function to return a dictionary.

The function did not work as expected. Instead of successfully converting the string to a dictionary, it throws a json.JSONDecodeError. The nested quotes within the string seem to be the root of the problem, and my function is not handling them correctly.

Comment: You have not-JSON data. The data cannot be parsed according to JSON rules. So according to what rules *can* it be parsed? ‍♂️ Probably none. The data is probably ambiguous. Whatever fix you’ll try, you’ll always be able to find edge cases that’ll fail. Because if there are no rules to follow, there is no one correct way of obtaining a result. TL;DR: ensure you get valid JSON data in the first place.

Comment: There's no good excuse for invalid JSON. There are JSON libraries for every popular language, so no one should have to roll their own and get it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

as others have commented, it can be hard to parse something if you don't have a specification for it.  But...sometimes life hands you lemons, and your job is to make lemonade.

Someone wrote a decoder for JSON already, and when there's an issue with it, the resulting exception has a `.pos` attribute that tells you exactly where the decoder got confused.  So this works for at least your stated case:

```py
import json


def fix_embedded_quotes(input_str):
    if input_str.count('"') % 2 != 0:
        raise ValueError("unbalanced quotes -- can't deal")

    while True:
        try:
            return json.loads(input_str)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as exc:
            # if the problem is at quote, we can try to fix it.  Otherwise, we
            # have bigger issues
            if input_str[exc.pos - 1] != '"':
                raise

            # escape our problem child
            input_str = (
                input_str[: exc.pos - 1] + '\\' + input_str[exc.pos - 1 :]
            )

            # escape the next quote
            next_quote = input_str.find('"', exc.pos + 1)
            input_str = (
                input_str[:next_quote] + '\\' + input_str[next_quote:]
            )


import unittest


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_valid_json(self):
        """first, do no harm"""
        result = fix_embedded_quotes(
            '{"foo" : "bar", "baz" : ["a", "b", "c"]}'
        )
        assert result['foo'] == 'bar'
        assert len(result['baz']) == 3

    def test_invalid_json(self):
        """ensure we deal with non-quote-related errors"""
        with self.assertRaises(json.decoder.JSONDecodeError):
            fix_embedded_quotes('{"foo" : "bar", "baz" : ["a", "b", "c"]')

    def test_original_case(self):
        result = fix_embedded_quotes(
            '{"text": "This is a "test" string","another_key": "Another value"}'
        )

        assert result['text'] == "This is a \"test\" string"
        assert result['another_key'] == "Another value"

    def test_quote_in_list(self):
        result = fix_embedded_quotes(
            '''["This is a "test" string",
                "Another value"
                ]
            '''
        )
        assert result[0] == "This is a \"test\" string"
        assert result[1] == "Another value"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```